# Open Multiple XL Files, Grab Data, then Write to Pandas/Output to Single Excel File

Tags: python, excel

I'm new to programming and python (using python27) and I'm trying to write code to open multiple excel files from a specific folder, grab specific cell values, and then output to a single excel file with each row representing records from each file opened.

Here is my code and I'm stuck on what the next process should be:

```
import os
import glob
import xlrd
import datetime


yesterday = datetime.date.fromordinal(datetime.date.today().toordinal()-1)

for root,dirs,files in os.walk(src):
    files = [ _ for _ in files if _.endswith('.xlsx') ]

for xlsfile in files:
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook(os.path.join(root,xlsfile))
    sht = wb.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
    name = xlsfile
    rev = sht.cell_value(0,1)
    gp = sht.cell_value(1,1)
    sls = sht.cell_value(2,1)
    sp = sht.cell_value(3,1)
    cps = sht.cell_value(4,1)
    print yesterday, name, rev, gp, sls, sp, cps
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the change to output to an xls file::

```
import os
import glob
import pyexcel as pe
import pyexcel.ext.xls
import xlrd
import datetime


yesterday = datetime.date.fromordinal(datetime.date.today().toordinal()-1)

for root,dirs,files in os.walk(src):
    files = [ _ for _ in files if _.endswith('.xlsx') ]

array = []

for xlsfile in files:
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook(os.path.join(root,xlsfile))
    sht = wb.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
    name = xlsfile
    rev = sht.cell_value(0,1)
    gp = sht.cell_value(1,1)
    sls = sht.cell_value(2,1)
    sp = sht.cell_value(3,1)
    cps = sht.cell_value(4,1)
    array.append([yesterday, name, rev, gp, sls, sp, cps])
    print yesterday, name, rev, gp, sls, sp, cps

pe.save_as(array=array, "myfile.xls")
```

More documentation can be found [here](http://pyexcel.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

Comment: thanks, this worked! i actually tweaked it to output to a pandas data frame and then out to a csv.  thank you again!

Comment: To save as csv, you could have had this: pe.save_as(array=array, "myfile.csv"). but I am glad the next step helped you proceed.